# Minimum sum of numbers

Tags: c

The code reads an input with numbers and find the sum with the minimum difference of the first two big numbers. The sums are three.

Is there is any way to make the code cleaner? (Note that I don't need to take any restrictions such as `NULL` parameters, etc)

Moreover, there is an `int` in my program `pA = -1` with that value. Now, because the `pA` used as pointer you see below that I have the statement `ProfitA = array[pA];`, that statement doesn't give any problems, but I just wanted to point it out in case you could clean my code a bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define min(ProfitA, ProfitB, ProfitC) ProfitA > (ProfitB > ProfitC ? ProfitB : ProfitC) ? ProfitA : (ProfitB > ProfitC ? ProfitB : ProfitC)

int main() {

    FILE* input = fopen("share.in","r");
    int bestMin = INT_MAX;
    int N = 0;
    fscanf(input,"%d",&N);

    int *array = malloc(N * sizeof(int));



    int pA = -1, pB = N - 1;
    int ProfitA = 0, ProfitC = 0, ProfitB = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fscanf(input,"%d",&array[i]);
        ProfitB += array[i];

    }


    ProfitB = ProfitB - array[pA] - array[pB];
    ProfitA = array[pA];
    ProfitC = array[pB];


    fclose(input);

    short flag = TRUE;
    int check_L = 0, check_R = 0;

    while ((pB - pA != 1) && (flag == TRUE)) {
        flag = FALSE;

        check_L += ProfitA + array[pA + 1];
        check_R += ProfitC + array[pB - 1];


        if (check_L < check_R) {

            ProfitA = check_L;
            ProfitB -= array[pA + 1];
            pA++;
            flag = TRUE;

        }
        else {

            ProfitC = check_R;
            ProfitB -= array[pB - 1];
            pB--;
            flag = TRUE;
        }
      check_R = 0, check_L = 0;

        printf("k1 = %d, k3 = %d, k2 = %d\n",ProfitA,ProfitB,ProfitC);

           int  currentMin = min(ProfitA, ProfitB, ProfitC); 

            if (currentMin < bestMin) {
                bestMin = currentMin;
            }


    }
    printf("%d\n",bestMin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How come pA = -1 is not a problem when accessing an array using that as index ?

Comment: i know it's a very bad problem in general (the array index start from 0) but in my case it works. If there is any way to kick it from my code then that's why I asked here ;) .

Comment: Please do not modify the original code based on answers.

Comment: @Jamal ok I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely can make your code cleaner :

- Your function *main* does all the job, that's usually quite bad. You can, at least, separate two aspects : reading the input (and store it in an array) and processing the input. That would be a little bit easier to read
- Use comments ! Not even one here, that's pretty bad.
- Better use of new lines : you really tend to use way too much of them. Multiple new lines should be used to separate parts of code that do quite different things, but in no case you should use two just after an *if*
- Better variable naming : just one example, but it's because it's very common : *i* . I really don't like it, because by reading the index, you don't know through what you iterate. The best example for that are matrices, *i* and *j* are far less understandable than *iRow* and *iCol*
- The indentation is also quite bad, especially at the end
- You don't *free* the memory you have allocated.
- Have you tried removing your condition on *flag* in your *while* ? You set it to false, then there's an if/else, and in both cases, it's set to true again.

Comment: ok I know I just don't have the time today to make my ocde cleaner. I just want to focus in the code itself. Thanks for the reply (take a thumps up!)

Comment: memory yes! Good point!

Comment: I can understand that you don't have the time, but you're more likely to have comments about the code rather than the aesthetics if the code looks nice.

Comment: in some of my others post people told me that is but cause I post the code for review so I should clean up the comments (which I didn't) What to believe anyway :)